# Menu Items display in action bar in 2.1, but not in 4.0.3, 4.2 (nexus 4)using ActionBarSherlock

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-actionbar

I am trying to implement ActionBarSherlock in my project.Adding menu/action items to the action bar is working on 2.1 but not in my nexus4, not in 4.0.3 emulator too. The problem is  the function  `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)`  never gets called in my device but gets called in 2.1 and hence no action items are shown in action bar in my phone.

1. I have included ActionBarSherlock as library in my project.
2. I have set appropriate theme in application in manifest file.
3. I have extended my activity class with SherlockActivity.
4. I have overriden appropriate class from sherlock library ( so far i know, if not, menu would not have been shown in action bar in 2.1 too)

Following is a part of manifest where theme is set.

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar" >
```

Following is menu.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_item_call"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="Call"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_item_share"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="Share"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_item_save"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="Save"/>

</menu>
```

Following is relevant part of the activity.

```
    //other imports
        import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity;
        import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu;
        import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater;
        import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Window;

        public class SelectCategories extends SherlockActivity implements
                OnClickListener {


        //other code


        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
            return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
//return true; also has no effect
        }
        }
```

I have been trying to solve this issue and it has been several hours but couldnt. Please help me.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Maybe set the android:theme in Activity too, or check your override class in sherlock library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally Figured out the issue.

Infact, I was trying to change existing project to use action bar. And Main thing is that the project uses TabActivity which is deprecated. Since ActionBarSherlock do not provide its custom implementation, I thought that it should be used as is. And that was my mistake. After removing tabactivity, I can see the menus in both versions.

Thank you alot for all who tried to help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to *return true;* instead of *super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);*

Answer (score 0):

Did you have these in onCreate

```
private ActionBar mActionBar;
mActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
// mActionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
// mActionBar.setDisplayOptions(0, ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);
```

need to import

```
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar;
```

Update: ActionBar

> Open Declaration
>
> com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar
>
> A window feature at the top of the activity that may display the
>   activity title, navigation modes, and other interactive items.
>
> Beginning with Android 3.0 (API level 11), the action bar appears at
>   the top of an activity's window when the activity uses the system's
>   Holo theme (or one of its descendant themes), which is the default.
>   You may otherwise add the action bar by calling
>   requestFeature(FEATURE_ACTION_BAR) or by declaring it in a custom
>   theme with the windowActionBar property.
>
> By default, the action bar shows the application icon on the left,
>   followed by the activity title. If your activity has an options menu,
>   you can make select items accessible directly from the action bar as
>   "action items". You can also modify various characteristics of the
>   action bar or remove it completely.
>
> From your activity, you can retrieve an instance of ActionBar by
>   calling getActionBar().
>
> In some cases, the action bar may be overlayed by another bar that
>   enables contextual actions, using an android.view.ActionMode. For
>   example, when the user selects one or more items in your activity, you
>   can enable an action mode that offers actions specific to the selected
>   items, with a UI that temporarily replaces the action bar. Although
>   the UI may occupy the same space, the android.view.ActionMode APIs are
>   distinct and independent from those for ActionBar.
>
> Developer Guides For information about how to use the action bar,
>   including how to add action items, navigation modes and more, read the
>   Action Bar developer guide.

Comment: But what to do with that object if we do not use it?

Comment: What do you mean, I only add this and my app work on both 2.3 and 4.0.3. remove the comment if that works for you, I comment it because I not sure that is suitable for you.

Comment: mActionBar has null value. Amazed. May be that is the reason.I have to figure it out.

Comment: null actionBar try add in onCreate `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR); //not sure which feature`

Answer (score 0):

This is the onCreateOptionsMenu function I use in my project with ActionBarSherlock:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
       getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
       return true;
    }
```

I wish I could tell you why yours is not working correctly.